# Multi-Threading on sockets C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to capture network packets from several IPs at the same time using threads, but i get this exception "*An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full*". I am new to threads and sockets. Exception come from "*mainSocket.BeginReceive(_data, 0, _data.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);*"

```
         IPHostEntry HosyEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()));
         if (HosyEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
         {
             foreach (IPAddress ip in HosyEntry.AddressList)
             {
                 if (ip.IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
                 {
                     SetIp ipAdd = new SetIp();
                     ipAdd.SetIpAdd(ip);    
                 }
             }
         }

    class SetIp
{
    private Socket mainSocket;                         
    private byte[] _data = new byte[4096];

    public void SetIpAdd(IPAddress address)
    {

        mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(address, 0));

         Thread MyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>{
             while (true)
             {

                 mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
                 byte[] byTrue = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                 byte[] byOut = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };

                 mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);


                 mainSocket.BeginReceive(_data, 0, _data.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);


             } }));

         MyThread.Start();
     }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        var received = mainSocket.EndReceive(ar);
        Parse(_data, received);
        mainSocket.BeginReceive(_data, 0, _data.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);

    }

    private void Parse(byte[] data, int size)
    {
        IPHeader ipHeader = new IPHeader(data, size);
        Console.WriteLine( ipHeader.SourceIP.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: show `_data` line where you initialize it please.

Comment: @DavidHaney - it is Initialized above the SetIpAdd method.

Comment: Right, and I'm asking you to show it as part of your code. :)

Comment: Typically speaking, it is not apprpriate to edit the question when an answer solves the problem. Now your original question no longer applies as you edited the code to fix the issue. Might be a good idea to undo your edit and post a separate answer so it's not confusing.

Comment: @rmayer06 sorry I am new to this, will undo it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `BeginReceive` infinitely often in a hot loop. This causes infinitely many IOs to queue up.

Probably, you want to use synchronous IO because it is simpler to use. Alternatively, only issue the next reado nce the last one has completed.

Comment: yes - you must issue one beginreceive and then wait for the call back. But you are doing multiple threads: it is much simpler to do sync receive - this call will block till there is data

Comment: @usr i didn't get what you are saying, as i am new to this, it would be great, if you can show me a tutorial or a code snippet how it is done.

Comment: There are tutorials for TCP servers all over the web.; You are running an infinite loop. And that loop never waits for anything. It calls BeginReceive millions of times per second. Instead, you probably only want to start the next receive when the previous receive has completed. Got it?

Comment: @usr i want to simultaneously capture packets from the IP addresses at the same time. So i cannot complete one IP and go to the next. how should i proceed with this?

Comment: Start one thread for each socket you are listening on. You need to have one outstanding read call per socket. I understand you have set your socket to listen on all IPs for everything. So you just have one socket and need only one thread. Does that make sense?

Comment: @usr Sorry I didn't get you, i am trying to read packets from multiple interfaces simultaneously at the same time.So basically what i am trying to do is select all connected IPs in the computer and capture packets from all of them at the same time. something similar to Wireshark.

Comment: So you have one socket, right? What's preventing you from just reading from that socket on a single thread?

Comment: @usr not one socket, i open one socket for each IPv4 address. I have edited the code. Please let me know if i am doing it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine. Run one thread per socket (you're doing that already - good). Now just read synchronously on each thread. Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: In general you should research *why* async IO is useful and in what cases. In yours it does not seem useful and it has disadvantages.

Comment: I didn't mean to discourage you from asking me questions. If there's still something unclear I'll help. I challenge your views as a teaching technique so that *you* discover why something is good or bad rather then me telling you.

Comment: @usr i added mainSocket.Receive(_data) after mainSocket.BeginReceive() method and now its working perfectly. (Edited the code) any recommendations you can give. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need both (in fact, because BeginReceive oeprates concurrently with the following receive call, your buffer might get overwritten at any time). Make yourself familiar with the difference between the two methods.

Comment: @usr I used only socket.receive and solved the issue. (I have edited the code)

Answer (score 1):

Used Receive method instead of the BeginReceive method.

```
    mainSocket.Receive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                ParseData(byteData, byteData.Length);
```